# Java specification

Tags: java

Java JDK or JRE or both are specifications?
Can anyone quote some relevant implementations?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The JDK (Java Developer Kit) and JRE (Java Runtime Environment) are (in part) both implementations of the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/) and The [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/).  JRE and JDK may or may not refer to the Sun JRE and Sun JDK depending on context.  You can see [this list of JVMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines) (Java Virtual Machines).  There are also third-party java compilers, the most popular being ecj and gcj.

Answer (score 1):

JDK means Java Development Kit. it provides you a tool or the files , key words , tokens or java extensions which helps to make a java program, its provide java tool to write java program or another Hand JRE that means Java Run-Time Environment which helps your OS to understand that what is going to be Run , in short if we says that JRE is same as OS, that provide an environment to execute java program .

Comment: @Eagle Please do not make edits that simply add bold formatting like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JDK is Java Development Kit, a toolset used to write Java programs. JRE is Java Runtime Environment, the virtual machine that executes Java bytecode. Naturally the Sun implementations of both are widely used

Answer (score 0):

JRE definition from [java.com](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/whatis_java.xml):

> The Java Runtime Environment (JRE) is
>   what you get when you download Java
>   software. The JRE consists of the Java
>   Virtual Machine (JVM), Java platform
>   core classes, and supporting Java
>   platform libraries. The JRE is the
>   runtime portion of Java software,
>   which is all you need to run it in
>   your Web browser.

And here is an article from wikipedia about what is [JDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit)